# ajax response deserialize before jquery parser

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have an api controller that would response a model with decimal property.
you know response type is just a simple string.
I know converting big decimal data to javascript number may lose some data.
so, I wanna convert a decimal(for instance number of varieties with more than 10) data to string before jquery json.parser ?

Answer (score 0):

You can parse manually with regexes. This (or something like it) should get you the string:

```
str.match(/"property_name": .+,/)
```

Then clip the rest like this:

```
matched_str.replace(/"property_name": /)
```

Clipping the comma off the end should be pretty simple as well. It's not the most elegant but it will get the job done.

Comment: `$.get("/api/values", {}, function (returnData) {});`
I have something like this but returnData is not a string, it's type is a json but my problem is not how to replace string, problem is how jquery parse string response ?! when ? where ?

Comment: Oh JQuery does this for you but you can manually make your own request. I believe this is what JQuery is doing under the hood. Read about it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_httprequest.asp). This will be more work though. Why is the API storing this value as a number when it is too big?

Comment: web api response is just a string, but problem is when jquery goes to parse it's string to json! it tries to convert a big decimal data to a type of number in javascript, in a case that we don't have a big data it's pretty cool but when data is so huge javascript number would lose some of data!

Comment: @AliKhalili did you look into the manual XMLHttp request from the link I sent you? I think this might be what you are looking for.

Comment: it's ok but how can use it in jquery ajax or angularjs http request ? not pure javascript ?

Comment: I mean whether is there any provider to do that or not ? may I should to change jquery or angularjs source code ?!

Comment: You definitely shouldn't change their source code, that will create a lot of problems for you. You should be able to do it with angular's http. I didn't know you were using angular.

Answer (score 0):

You've to develop jQuery Ajax Setup, angular $http interceptor, whatever, when you get response instance, you can do the following:

```
 if (response.body != null && typeof response.body === "string") {

      response.body = (response.body as string).replace(/:\s*(\d{14,}.\d{2,})\s*([,\}])/g, ':"$1"$2');

      // this will change "{ number : 214748364711111.2 }" to "{ number : '214748364711111.2' }"

  }
```

Note that you've to change response before the underlying framework calls JSON.parse.

For jQuery this means $( document ).ajaxComplete method.
More details at https://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/